Spark Grouped Record Processing
Before writing here, I checked-out following , but didn't get clue to resolve my issue:
Spark data processing with grouping
 
I have a Java Spark 3.5 job running on EMR 7.
Following is my input dataset:



some-id
value1-of-some-id
value2-of-some-id
value3-of-some-id




A1000000000
Value-One-Row1000000000
Value-Two-Row10000000000
Value-Three-Row100000000


B1000000000
Value-One-Row2000000000
Value-Two-Row20000000000
Value-Three-Row200000000


C1000000000
Value-One-Row3000000000
Value-Two-Row30000000000
Value-Three-Row300000000


A1000000000
Value-One-Row4000000000
Value-Two-Row40000000000
Value-Three-Row400000000


B1000000000
Value-One-Row5000000000
Value-Two-Row50000000000
Value-Three-Row500000000


A1000000000
Value-One-Row6000000000
Value-Two-Row60000000000
Value-Three-Row600000000



Now, my requirement is to do grouping based upon Field : "some-id", generate an XML String as depicted below, and, save that XML string into a Parquet file, exclusively created for *each of the value of some-id field *:
<root-of-some-record some-id = 'A1000000000'>

 <values>
  <value id="1"> Value-One-Row1000000000 </value>
  <value id="2"> Value-Two-Row10000000000 </value>
  <value id="3"> Value-Three-Row100000000 </value>
 </values>

</root-of-some-record>



Similar, XML String (exclusive for each value of "some-id"), has to be created for rest of the some-id and saved into their respective, Parquet files.
In total 3 Parquet files has to be generated for those 3 values of Field : "some-id".

Following is the code, I wrote to fetch grouped records, but it's failing by saying that value1-of-some-id is not part of the grouping fields.

     session.sql("select some-id, collect_list(value1-of-some-id) , collect_list(value2-of-some-id) , collect_list(value3-of-some-id)  from <some-data-source> group by some-id").createOrReplaceTempView("temp1");


I then, wrote following code, but it's taking 45 minutes to process my 10 Million workload, which is against SLA. SLA is 20 minutes. EMR 7 cluster with 5 core & 15 Task nodes is used here.

    ds.groupBy("some-id").as(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.row(<schema-struct>)).mapGroups(<assume-mapFunction-is-doing-XML-generation-part-here>);

So, Can you please suggest, any alternative, to fetch grouped records, along with all field values (except by using approach # 2 depicted above)?
